# Unable to call service across different namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to build an simple application where I am using Kafka as message broker and java spring boot based microservice application as a consumer. I am using minikube cluster for container orchestration. When I am trying to access service of kafka from a different namspace, I am not being able to do so. Below is my kafka. file for kafka configuration -

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-deployment
  namespace: pos
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: broker
          image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: kafka-config
                  key: zookeeper-url
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka-service:9092
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-service
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: pos
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30092
```

Below is my zookeeper service configuration -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-service
  name: zookeeper-service
  namespace: pos
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-port
      port: 2182
      nodePort: 30181
      targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: pos
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
```

Below is the configmap for kafka -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kafka-config
  namespace: pos
data:
  zookeeper-url: zookeeper-service:2182
```

Below is the pod and service config for application -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: customer-app-deployment
  namespace: customer
  labels:
    app: customer-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: customer-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: customer-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: customer-app
          image: abhishek050990/customer-app:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9081
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: DB_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: customer-app-config
                  key: customer-db-url
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              value: "root"
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: "root"
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_SERVER_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: customer-app-config
                  key: kafka-consumer-url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: customer-app-service
  namespace: customer
spec:
  selector:
    app: customer-app
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9081
      targetPort: 9081
      nodePort: 30081
```

Below is the configmap for the application -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: customer-app-config
  namespace: customer
data:
  kafka-consumer-url: kafka-service.pos.svc.cluster.local
  customer-db-url: customer-db-service:6033
```

As you can see here I am using 'kafka-consumer-url: kafka-service.pos.svc.cluster.local' to access the kafka service, but I am unable to do so, it is showing error as "java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-service". Please help me out.

Tried to access the pod using - kubectl exec -it pod/customer-app-deployment-6c4d455485-9tbkk sh -n customer and from there I pinged the service using - ping kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, but showing error as -
--- kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
75 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Comment: Firstly, don't roll your own Kafka - https://strimzi.io/ Secondly - you should be using a headless service

Comment: Also, not clear what DNS service is running on your cluster, or what network policies exist on your namespaces

Comment: I haven't added any network policies. everything is default from minikube , even the DNS service as well which is present in minikube.

Comment: as per my knowledge service.namspace.svc.cluster.local should be enough for cross namspace communication which is not happening here.

Comment: It should with CoreDNS, yes.... The strimzi docs explain how to get started with minikube. Also take a read through https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/

Comment: Also see DNS troubleshooting guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-if-the-dns-pod-is-running

Comment: in my kafka.yml I added  
 - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
    value: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092,
worked for me .

Comment: Feel free to put an answer below rather than a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my updated lines of code for kafka configuration, where I made the change and it's working -

```
 name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
   value: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka- 
   service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

As we can see, I have added the namesapce info to the advertised listener.